# Deleting duplicate polygon using QGIS

Tags: qgis, delete, duplication

I am using QGIS "Delete Duplicate Geometries" tool, I am trying to delete one of the below two polygons , but failed.

The below two polygons are identical with vertices , but the start of the vertices is different.

How to identify those and delete it using QGIS?

MultiPolygon (((1087121.56094263 4537352.23808735, 1087121.5609641 4537352.23808582, 1087124.60834866 4537351.52946457, 1087127.2876076 4537349.9138321, 1087129.33647638 4537347.54933776, 1087130.55439745 4537344.66743475, 1087130.82215222 4537341.55022379, 1087130.11353097 4537338.50283923, 1087128.4978985 4537335.82358029, 1087126.13340417 4537333.77471151, 1087123.25150115 4537332.55679044, 1087120.13430105 4537332.28903661, 1087117.08692558 4537332.99764883, 1087114.40766316 4537334.61327553, 1087112.35878929 4537336.97776546, 1087111.14086201 4537339.85966585, 1087110.87310054 4537342.97687623, 1087111.58171523 4537346.02426232, 1087113.19734193 4537348.70352473, 1087115.56183186 4537350.7523986, 1087118.44373225 4537351.97032588, 1087121.56094263 4537352.23808735)))

MultiPolygon (((1087120.13430105 4537332.28903661, 1087117.08692558 4537332.99764883, 1087114.40766316 4537334.61327553, 1087112.35878929 4537336.97776546, 1087111.14086201 4537339.85966585, 1087110.87310054 4537342.97687623, 1087111.58171523 4537346.02426232, 1087113.19734193 4537348.70352473, 1087115.56183186 4537350.7523986, 1087118.44373225 4537351.97032588, 1087121.56094263 4537352.23808735, 1087121.5609641 4537352.23808582, 1087124.60834866 4537351.52946457, 1087127.2876076 4537349.9138321, 1087129.33647638 4537347.54933776, 1087130.55439745 4537344.66743475, 1087130.82215222 4537341.55022379, 1087130.11353097 4537338.50283923, 1087128.4978985 4537335.82358029, 1087126.13340417 4537333.77471151, 1087123.25150115 4537332.55679044, 1087120.13430105 4537332.28903661)))

Comment: Get their area and if exactly the same, you have a duplicate as quite improbable exact area between 2 polygons.

Comment: You should check also the perimeter and the bounding box of the two polygons to be sure they are identical.

Comment: You can give a try to Check Geometries plugin, there is a Check for duplicates option in the Topology checks section. Another tool is the Topology Checker plugin to find duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Both Check Geometries plugin and Topology Checker plugin can find duplicate polygons.

1. Find the **Geometry Checker** (it is a core plugin, you have to enable only) plugin in the Vector menu. On the Setup tab of the dialog of the plugin select the layers to check. Find Check for duplicates in the topology section. In the output vector layers section you have to select Modify input layer or Create new layer. Then select Run button.

[image]

[image]

I've create a single part polygon and a multi part polygon layer. In both case the vertices are identical but the orders are different. The duplicate multi part polygons trigger two errors one for the duplicate enclave and another for the whole multi part polygon.
You can select correction method to eliminate error.

[image]

2. The **Topology checker** is also a core plugin. Find the Topology checker in the vector menu. It opens a new panel, in the toolbar of the panel select Configure button (the third one) to define rules.

[image]

Close the configure dialog and use the first tool to check the whole layers.

[image]

This case the duplicate multi part polygons cause only single error. Double click on the error row to zoom on feature. No auto correction is available here.

Comment: What QGIS version  are you using?  I ask because at 3.16.3 I do not see the tool **Geometry Checker**, either within *Vector >*, or within *Processing > Toolbox*, or in *Plugins*.

Comment: I use 3.18 but this plugins are available in 3.16 too. I think you forgot enable these plugins from the menu Plugins/Manage and Install Plugins.

Comment: You are correct, thanks.  I now see it in the Plugins.